# "Confirm navigation" alertbox

Tags: javascript, alert, confirm

I'm looking for an function that shows a alertbox when the visitor is trying to leave the page when he or she haven't finished the form. I have imported an image to show what I mean. Translation: title = "Confirm navigation", content = "Do you want to leave this page?", button1 = "Leave this page", button2 = "Stay on this page".

Facebook uses this alertbox when you want to go back one page when you have for example not finished an PM to someone.

[image]

How can I accomplish something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `window.onbeforeunload` in conjunction with a flag that gets set when a change is made to a form field.

For example:

```
var changed_flag = 0; // change in an onchange event or whatever, something like the below

document.getElementById('form_field').onchange = function() {
  changed_flag = 1;
};

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if ( changed_flag ) {
    return 'You have unsubmitted changes.'
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks but nothing happens when I try your solution :/ I have the code within the script tag in a file that are included on every page.

Comment: Did you try it with the onchange handler?

Comment: I have tested your edit and I have still the same problem :/ The form on the page has id="form_field"

Comment: If you post an example on jsFiddle I'll take a look.

Comment: The id needs to be on the field itself. I changed it and it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/RZr8B/2/

Comment: Super! Many thanks :) But how can I make it work on every form and not just one input?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, one of which is to bind to all inputs generically. Using jQuery for shorthand: `$('input').change(function() {changed_flag = 1})`. You can then include this and the `onbeforeunload` function in a script tag on every page and it should work. NOTE: You may want to get fancier and serialize the form first so you can compare changed values later. This would prevent the onbeforeunload message if someone changed something and then changed it back to how it was before.

Comment: Wonderful! :) Many thanks once again and I'll keep your advice in mind :)

Comment: Hi! I have one more question about this function. When I'm hitting submit it shows the alertbox. How can I prevent this?

Comment: what if I want to customize the button? or my custom javascript event ?